# Remove all rows which each value is the same

Tags: pandas

I want to drop all rows that have same values by `drop_duplicates(subset=['other_things','Dist_1','Dist_2'])` but could not get it.

## Input

```
  id  other_things  Dist_1  Dist_2
    1   a             a       a
    2   a             b       a
    3   10            10      10
    4   a             b       a
    5   8             12      48
    6   8             12      48
```

## Expeted

```
  id  other_things  Dist_1  Dist_2
    2   a             b       a
    4   a             b       a
    5   8             12      48
    6   8             12      48
```

## Try

```
df =  df.drop_duplicates()
```

Comment: please specify which columns to consider for dropping duplictes

Comment: Use `df[df.duplicated(subset=['other_things','Dist_1','Dist_12'], keep=False)]`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the 'id' column could be generating problems.

Would recommend using the 'subset' parameter on drop duplicates as per the documentation.

drop_duplicates documentation[1](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html)